# What does that code line means in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I was studying one code and I saw this:

```
var $notes = $('<ol id="notes"></ol>');
```

I thought it was the same thing of

```
 var $notes = $('ol#notes');
```

But I tested it and its not the same thing.....

Can someone enlight me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line creates a new element represented by the markup. The second matches existing elements in the DOM already.

Comment: It's actually a document fragment.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - Actually, according to the documentation, if the string looks like HTML jQuery will try to parse it and create the DOM elements. The jQuery wrapper returned by the call wraps the newly created DOM element. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 2):

[This section in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) may explain the meaning of the line in question.

Comment: +1 What I like from the *Documentation* is that they're probably right ;)